# Select & type control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am looking out for combination of TextBox & ComboBox in WPF. i.e. user should be able to enter new text values or select one from drop down list.

Is there any pre-existing control for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just `ComboBox` with `IsEditable` property set to `True`? :

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"/>
```

With that user will be able to *enter new text values, or select one from drop down list.* Or type to search value from drop down list.